# gulp - Exclude file not working

Tags: node.js, gulp

In my gulpfile I have a task which builds and writes everything to a `dist` folder. Now I'm trying to write another task that cleans out everything in `dist` **except** for my vendor bundle. This is what I have so far:

```
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./dist', '!./dist/scripts/vendor.js'])
        .pipe($.clean());
});
```

When I run this it deletes `dist` altogether. What's the right way to exclude just one file?

Note: I've also tried using `gulp-ignore` and `gulp-filter` with the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/165) Github issue led me in the right direction. The pattern I wanted was

`['dist/*, '!dist/scripts{,/vendor.js}']`.

If anyone knows of any good globbing docs that would be super helpful :)

Comment: https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch  string matching module, has some information in the readme

Comment: Here are examples: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/11/building-with-gulp/

Comment: I have no idea why this was so difficult to find.