# Ignore files that have a hash in them with Gulp

Tags: regex, gulp, wildcard

With gulp I want to ignore images that have a revision hash in the filename. `my-image-123abcd.png`.

```
gulp.task('custom', function() {
    return gulp.src(['public/dist/images/**/*'])
        .pipe(doSomething())
        //etc
});
```

How can I achieve this in gulp?

Comment: To ignore somethng, you need to use a `!` before the pattern. If you need to ignore patterns with `-<number>`, you may try something like `'!public/dist/images/**/*-+[0-9].png'`

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790544/gulp-exclude-file-not-working